# Profile edit page still says "edit your profile" when editing someone else's profile as a moderator

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, wording, profile-edit

When a moderator opens the page to edit a user's profile info, all text is in the second person, like it is in the moderator's personal profile.

> [image: "Edit your profile"]

For example:

> Edit your profile

This should be something like:

> Edit this user's profile

Also, when you save the changes, the message is

> Your profile has been saved successfully.